# Same python interpreter but json_set only not working on Visual Studio Code, works everywhere else

Tags: python, sql, json, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I'm not being able to wrap my head around.

Exactly the same code, exactly the same interpreter, works everywhere else but not on `Visual Studio Code`.

Let's consider the following example:

```py
import sqlite3


_connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
_connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

create_table = """
    create table food (
        id int not null,
        data json not null,
        primary key(id)
    )
"""

insert = """
    insert into food (id, data)
    values (1, '{"name": "Steak"}')
"""

update = """
    update food
    set data = json_set(data, '$.name', 'Bacon and Eggs')
    where id = 1
"""

fetch_query = "select json_extract(data, '$.name') as name from food where id = 1"

with _connection:
        _connection.execute(create_table)
        _connection.execute(insert)
        _connection.execute(update)
        food = _connection.execute(fetch_query)

new_food = dict(food.fetchone()).get('name')
print(new_food)
```

It should print out `Bacon and Eggs` but `Visual Studio Code` complains `json_set` is not a function.

How do I check what version of `sqlite3` is being used by `Visual Studio Code` internally? Not sure why running it from vs code doesn't behave the same as running it from an external terminal.

## Update 1

Linux Terminal

[image: Works on system terminal]

Visual Studio Code
[image: no such function: json_set]

## Update 2

I'm not relying on VS code to figure out which version of python to use. I'm typing it explicitly. Nothing to do with `pip` I suppose. I'm using the same version of `pip` anyways.

Vs code
[image: json_set function not found]

Linux terminal
[image: works fine]

Comment: How do you judge "exactly the same interpreter"? Since in VS Code, its internal terminal is integrated from the system terminal, if the code can run in the system terminal, it is recommended that you use the command "_pip --version_" or "_python --version_" in the internal terminal of VS Code to check its python.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the same python interpreter and installation is being used by everything? It doesn't sound like it.

Comment: @Shawn Please refer to the screenshots.

Comment: @JillCheng If I'm not mistaken, I have used the same interpreter located at `/usr/bin/python3`. Please refer to the screenshot above.

Comment: It seems that the "pwd" command shows the path of the executable file,
And is "/usr/bin/python3" you input? It does not show the python version currently used by the terminal.

Please use the command "python --version" (or "python -v") to check whether the two terminals use the same python.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jill and Shawn.

Turns out `Visual Studio Code` is using a different version of `sqlite3` under the hood than the system.

I just had to `pip install pysqlite3-binary`.

and

```py
import pysqlite3 as sqlite3
...
```

everything else is unchanged.

I am pretty sure there are other ways to solve this problem but this is how I did it.